Error "text_jni.so': dlopen failed: library "libtask_text_jni.so" not found"
I am trying to use the tflite_flutter and tflite_flutter_helper_plus libraries in the following versions:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  tflite_flutter: ^0.10.4
  tflite_flutter_helper_plus: ^0.0.2

Here is my implementation, which follows the documentation.
https://github.com/odejinmi/tflite_flutter_helper_plus
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tflite_flutter_helper_plus/tflite_flutter_helper_plus.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});


  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () { getAnswer();},
          child: Text('click me to get answer'),
        ),
      )
    );
  }


  void getAnswer() async {
    String question = "What is the capital of Brazil?";
    String context = "Brazil is a country in South America. It is the largest country in South America and the fifth largest country in the world. The capital of Brazil is Brasília.";
    final bertQuestionAnswerer = await BertQuestionAnswerer.createFromAsset('assets/bert_qa.tflite');
    List<QaAnswer> answeres = bertQuestionAnswerer.answer(context, question);
    print(answeres);
   }
}

But I am getting this error:
E/flutter (12951): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'libtask_text_jni.so': dlopen failed: library "libtask_text_jni.so" not found
E/flutter (12951): #0      _open (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:11:43)
E/flutter (12951): #1      new DynamicLibrary.open (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:22:12)
E/flutter (12951): #2      tflitelib.<anonymous closure> (package:tflite_flutter_helper_plus/src/task/bindings/dlib.dart:32:27)
E/flutter (12951): #3      tflitelib (package:tflite_flutter_helper_plus/src/task/bindings/dlib.dart:40:2)
E/flutter (12951): #4      tflitelib (package:tflite_flutter_helper_plus/src/task/bindings/dlib.dart)
E/flutter (12951): #5      BertQuestionAnswererFromFile (package:tflite_flutter_helper_plus/src/task/bindings/text/qa/bert_qa.dart:13:32)
E/flutter (12951): #6      BertQuestionAnswererFromFile (package:tflite_flutter_helper_plus/src/task/bindings/text/qa/bert_qa.dart)
E/flutter (12951): #7      BertQuestionAnswerer.create (package:tflite_flutter_helper_plus/src/task/text/qa/bert_question_answerer.dart:42:23)
E/flutter (12951): #8      BertQuestionAnswerer.createFromAsset (package:tflite_flutter_helper_plus/src/task/text/qa/bert_question_answerer.dart:78:12)
E/flutter (12951): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12951): #9      _MyHomePageState.getAnswer (package:bert_qa_teste/main.dart:56:34)
E/flutter (12951): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12951): 

I tried changing the Android version by emulating more recent versions. I would like to understand this error and, if possible, get a solution.

there is a file missing in the 'android/app/src/main' folder.
Download the folder named 'jniLibs/arm64-v8a' from this link https://github.com/am15h/tflite_flutter_helper/tree/master/example/bert_question_answer/android/app/src/main
Add it to your project at the path mentioned before, and it should run successfully.

Please don't use link only answers. Provide the code in the answer to ensure we don't lose the context if this repo is ever deleted.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
